# UIScrollView With Large Number of Images To Show

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I would like to setup a UIScrollView containing say 5 images to be scrolled.
I have 100 images to be scrolled.
The strategy I am using is as follows:
1. Load and setup images 1 2 3 4 5.
2. Scroll by 1 and move images in subviews such that I now have 2 3 4 5 6 in the same subview set.
3. Scroll again until end and wrap images in subviews.

I have got the image moves to work but cannot scroll out of the 1 2 3 4 5 set.
I can see the next image but cannot get to it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use a table with a custom view that displays the image. That way, all the scrolling and swapping will be handled for you.

Comment: Great idea that might work with a landscape table and the images rotated.  Not sure if this would solve the wrapping of the images at the start and end boundaries.

Comment: If you design the tableview cells properly I don't think you'll have a problem. I think you'll also want to turn off the scroll bounce.